# Python writing AVRO timestamp-millis: datum.astimezone(tz=timezones.utc) AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'astimezone'

Tags: python, python-3.x, timestamp, avro

Environment: python 3.8.4 under Windows 10.

I am trying to write avro from dictionary.

Dictionary contains timestamp

```
def get_dict(self):
        return {"msg_header": {...
                                 "msg_timestamp": int(datetime.datetime.timestamp(datetime.datetime.now())),
                               ...},
                ...
                 }
```

Avro schema:

```
{
        "name" : "msg_timestamp",
        "type" : {
          "type" : "long",
          "logicalType" : "timestamp-millis"
}
```

Writing Avro:

```
writer = avro.io.DatumWriter(schema)
bytes_writer = io.BytesIO()
encoder = avro.io.BinaryEncoder(bytes_writer)
writer.write(get_dict(), encoder) #----------Exception here
raw_bytes = bytes_writer.getvalue()
```

Exception:

> ```
> ...
> line
> 581, in write_timestamp_millis_long
>     datum = datum.astimezone(tz=timezones.utc)  
> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'astimezone'
> ```

Any ideas how to fix it? I do not want conversion to UTC. Even if I set system TZ to UTC, it does not help, method astimezone(tz=timezones.utc) is being executed causing exception

Comment: `datum` seems to be an integer (Unix time in seconds), so you'll have to convert to datetime object first to use `astimezone` method. Also, what do you mean by "*I do not want conversion to UTC*" - which time zone to you need? Local time? Unix time refers to UTC so you won't get around a conversion.

Comment: @MrFuppes I am not calling .asdatetime explicitly, it is exception message, it is being called internally. My code in as provided in question. If I use datetime.datetime.now() instead of  int(datetime.datetime.timestamp(datetime.datetime.now())) I get "the datum is not an example of the schema" Is it any way to tell python that timezone is UTC (actually it is not UTC) to avoid conversion?

Answer (score 2):

Finally I ended up using fastavro, it provides more verbose exception messages rather than "the datum ... is not an example of the schema...", it works without any issue and process a list of messages.

```
import fastavro
...
parsed_schema = fastavro.schema.load_schema(schema_path)
...
def get_dict(self):
    return {"msg_header": {...
                             "msg_timestamp": int(datetime.datetime.timestamp(datetime.datetime.now())),
                           ...},
            ...
             }
...

#in a for loop do something and Prepare list of messages 
messages.append(get_dict().copy())
...

bytes_writer = io.BytesIO()
fastavro.writer(bytes_writer, parsed_schema, messages)
raw_bytes = bytes_writer.getvalue()
```

Answer (score 1):

`msg_timestamp` is defined as a logical type so that means your dictionary should contain a `datetime` and the library will automatically convert it to a `long` when serializing and back to a `datetime` when deserializing.

So instead of:

```
"msg_timestamp": int(datetime.datetime.timestamp(datetime.datetime.now()))
```

You just want to do:

```
"msg_timestamp": datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

If instead you want to turn it to an int yourself and not have the library do it, don't use `logicalType`.

Comment: this  causing "the datum is not an example of the schema"  exception

Comment: Sorry, it needs to be timezone aware, so for example something like this: {"msg_timestamp": datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.timezone.utc)}